# Difflib throwing error on tags that don't change

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, difflib

I'm having a weird issue with difflib. I'm trying to pull out the differences between two urls, grouped by html tag in a list. This works fine on a subset of the html -- if there was an actual change, or if the tag didn't exist -- but is not working when there are no changes. For example, the two URLs I'm scraping have identical  tags. I would expect it to give me an empty list if there was no change and move on, but instead it throws an error (the error generally is that it can't do anything with a type other than string).

I've tried to correct this by wrapping the difflist in a string, but that produces an entirely empty list. I've also tried to check if the type is a string, and that's still not working -- the issue seems to be in this line:

```
 changes = [change for change in difflist if change.startswith('-') or change.startswith('+')]
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
from lxml import html, etree
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import difflib

url1 = 'https://www.example.com/1'
url2 = 'https://www.example.com/2'

site1 = requests.get(url1)
doc1 = html.fromstring(site1.content)
tree1 = etree.tostring(doc1,encoding='utf-8',method='html')
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(tree1, "lxml")

site2 = requests.get(url2)
doc2 = html.fromstring(site2.content)
tree2 = etree.tostring(doc2,encoding='utf-8',method='html')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(tree2, "lxml")

tag_library = ['a', 'abbr', 'address', 'area', 'article', 'aside', 'audio', 'b', 'base', 'bdi', 'bdo', 'blockquote', 'body', 'br', 'button', 'canvas', 'caption', 'cite', 'code', 'col', 'colgroup', 'data', 'datalist', 'dd', 'del', 'details', 'dfn', 'dialog', 'div', 'dl', 'dt', 'em', 'embed', 'fieldset', 'figure', 'footer', 'form', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'head', 'header', 'hgroup', 'hr', 'html', 'i', 'iframe', 'img', 'input', 'ins', 'kbd', 'keygen', 'label', 'legend', 'li', 'link', 'main', 'map', 'mark', 'menu', 'menuitem', 'meta', 'meter', 'nav', 'noscript', 'object', 'ol', 'optgroup', 'option', 'output', 'p', 'param', 'pre', 'progress', 'q', 'rb', 'rp', 'rt', 'rtc', 'ruby', 's', 'samp', 'script', 'section', 'select', 'small', 'source', 'span', 'strong', 'style', 'sub', 'summary', 'sup', 'table', 'tbody', 'td', 'template', 'textarea', 'tfoot', 'th', 'thead', 'time', 'title', 'tr', 'track', 'u', 'ul', 'var', 'video', 'wbr']

tag_library2 = ['abbr', 'h1', 'p', 'nav', 'img']

d = difflib.Differ()
diff = []
for tag in tag_library:
    difflist = d.compare(soup1.find_all(tag), soup2.find_all(tag))
    changes = [change for change in difflist if change.startswith('-') or change.startswith('+')]
    diff.append(changes)

print(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out -- had to go into each list, split it up, and convert each item to a string:

```
for tag in tag_library2:
    list1 = soup1.find_all(tag)
    list1split = []
    for el in list1:
        list1split.append(str(el))
    list2 = soup2.find_all(tag)
    list2split = []
    for el in list2:
        list2split.append(str(el))

    difflist = d.compare(list1split, list2split)
#    if difflist.contains(str):
    changes = [change for change in difflist if change.startswith('-') or change.startswith('+')]
    diff.append(changes)
```